# Is PCA suitable when there are continuous variables with many zeros?

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction, bias, pcoa

I am dealing with a database where frequencies of behaviors are recorded, thus being continuous data but with many zeros. Aiming to reduce the dimensions of the seven variables, I have carried out a principal component analysis. I was wondering if this methodology is appropriate for this kind of data set, or whether it is preferable to use other methods such as NDMS or PCoA.

Comment: Could you explain your intended meanings of "appropriate" and "preferable"? After all, PCA will *always* succeed in reducing the dimensions.  But that's almost never the objective of an analysis: dimension reduction is a preliminary step towards something else.  What do you want to do?

Comment: We aimed to apply the PCA to reduce the number of behavioral variables recorded for our species model. Secondly, each PC would be considered as a response variable of a GLMM. The doubt lies in whether applying a PCA for a database with many zeros may bias the results obtained in the first step.